# SQL select command using string with comma separated IDs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select, wildcard

I have a string in PHP like:

```
"1234,2345,4567,5676,234,12,78957".....
```

I want to extract these numbers in varchar(30) format and use them on a command like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%NUM';
```

where NUM will have above mentioned 7 strings.

And if possible i would also like to restrict '%' in '%NUM' to 1-5 characters only i.e. the prefix should not be greater than 5 characters. Example NUM = 1234 and ID has (31234,5678956781234) it should only provide first one as result and not the other one.

Accordingly I will get a merged result of all matching rows.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank You!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: If you _ever_ find yourself having to process sub-columnar data (extracting parts of a column), you're doing it wrong :-) Fix the schema and your queries will scream along.

Comment: @paxdiablo: this isn't sub-columnar data... it's a list of ID's he'd like to search on

Comment: Where is this string of numbers coming from?

Comment: it will come in form of a php variable say $ids

Comment: @GleonApps So why not `explode` the string in PHP and build a better query?

Answer (score 2):

If that string is coming from a column somewhere in the database, you should fix the schema. It's almost *always* a bad idea to design a schema where you have to process sub-columnar data.

If it's a string from *outside* the database and you just want to run queries based on the individual parts, you're probably better off using facilities *outside* of your DBMS to construct the queries.

For example, using `bash` under Linux:

```
pax> list="1234,2345,4567,5676,234,12,78957"
pax> for i in $(echo $list | sed 's/,/ /g'); do
...>     echo mysql "\"SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%$i'\""
...> done
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%1234'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%2345'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%4567'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%5676'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%234'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%12'"
mysql "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM WHERE ID LIKE '%78957'"
```

That script will *echo* the commands to do what you want (assuming `mysql` is the correct CLI interface to your DBMS) - simply remove the `echo` at the start to actually *execute* the commands.

---

For PHP (as per your question edit), you can use the [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to split the string, something like:

```
$list = "1234,2345,4567,5676,234,12,78957";
$numbers = explode (",", $list);
```

then execute a query for each element of `$numbers`.

---

If what you're after is a *single* result set formed from all of those values, there are other ways to do it. One involves using the list to construct an "uber-query" string that will do all the work for you, then you execute it once.

Simply use an `or` clause to join the different "sub" queries into one (pseudo-code):

```
$query = "select * from table_num"
$joiner = " where"
for each $element in $list:
    $query = $query + $joiner + "id like '%" + $element + "'"
    $joiner = " or"
execute_sql $query
```

That ends up giving you the query string:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NUM
    WHERE ID LIKE '%1234'
    OR    ID LIKE '%2345'
    :
    OR    ID LIKE '%78957'
```

Comment: i want a merged result of all these not singled out.

Comment: As the php query result will be further processed. I guess a proper SQL stored procedure will be more useful.

Comment: Okay, @Gleon, I've added a method for constructing a _single_ query which will extract all desired rows. My PHP knowledge is not up to the level where I'm confident providing bug-free code so I've just given pseudo-code.

Comment: would this slow down as I will have over 100 IDs in one String. I doing something like this in SQL will be faster. and can you also check out my edit in question regarding restriction to '%'.

Comment: @Gleon, it's almost certainly going to be slow anyway since you use `%xxx` as the argument. Some DBMS' can alleviate this by using reversed indexes. Worry about functionality first, _then_ question performance. You can't get any less optimal than "wrong" :-)

Comment: so what will be better php function OR SQL procedure?

Comment: *"You can't get any less optimal than "wrong""* ~ that's a viable office motivational poster right there